# CakePHP: Getting a blank page when renaming the folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I am working on a cakephp project locally then when I'm uploading it to the remote server I upload it as "projectName-new". And after doing some tests it is renamed to "projectName" and after renaming the original "projectName" to "projcetName-old".

However after renaming the new one from "projectName-new" to "projectName" I'm getting a blank page. but when I rename it back or rename it to any other name than "projectName" I can view it properly, also when I rename the "projectName-old" to "projectName" I can view that project properly.

I thought it might be something with the `.htaccess` but there's nothing weird in the file. Any ideas to why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you restart the webserver? It is probably caching part of the data.

Comment: enable debug mode from 0 to 2, it will show you the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it was something in the .htaccess, I changed the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And removed the $1 to be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Blank page usually means either you don't have debug at 1 or more (see "[debugging](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html)" in the CakePHP book) or you have a space or whitespace after a closing `?>` tag at the end of one of your files.

Comment: Nope it wasn't, eventually it was something the .htaccess, check my answer :)